# How to match 'abbbc' in 'aaabbbccc' by using re module in python3?

Tags: python, string

I have a problem in string matching. It's just similar to matching 'abbbc' in 'aaabbbccc', note that there are uncertain number of characters between 'aaa' and 'ccc', and I should match 'abbbc' in it, only one 'a' and one 'c'. I attempt to use 'a[\d\D]+?c' but failed, if I insist to use the format of 'a@@@c' to achieve this, how to write it? Or is there any other regular expression to achieve it?

```
>>> import re

>>> string = 'aaabbbccc'
>>> res = re.findall(r'a[\d\D]+?c', string)
>>> print(res)
['aaabbbc']
```

Comment: Are the b always the same character?

Comment: No. 'b' just represent the uncertain characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop the middle section from starting with `a` by splitting "one or more of anything", `[\d\D]+?`, into "not an a" then "zero or more of anything", `[^a][\d\D]*?`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `a(.)\1\1c` is a more specific `a...c` that requires all three dots to be the same character. Both of these would match `abbbc` in `aaabbbccc`. But the first would not match anything in `aaabbdccc` whereas the second would have a match of `abbdc`.

Comment: I found both of your methods work, thank you. Then if there are uncertain number of characters between 'aaa' and 'ccc', I just want to match 'a@@@c', only one 'a' and 'c', how to achieve it?

Comment: If you want them to all be the same, perhaps `a(?:(.)\1*)?b`.